# Overlaying a Scatter plot with a Density (bivariate) using Seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

As the title reads, I am trying to overlay a scatter plot with a bivariate density using Seaborn. I am very new with this package so it is possible the answer is obvious. Here is my current code. (Taken from https://elitedatascience.com/python-seaborn-tutorial#)

```
# Density overlayed with Scatter
#Set figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

# Plots
sns.kdeplot(df.Attack,
            df.Defense)

sns.lmplot(x='Attack',
          y='Defense',
          hue='Stage',
          data=df,
          fit_reg=False)

plt.title('Density vs Scatter')
```

My issue is that these appear as 2 separate plots. The tutorial implies that this overlay should be simple.

edit: here is my result

[Density](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vno47.png)

[Scatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiKc1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read seaborn's [doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html#seaborn.lmplot), you will see that `sns.lmplot()` combines `regplot()` and `FacetGrid` while `sns.kdeplot()` returns a `Axes` object. Thus, you may want to use the figure-level function `sns.regplot()` instead so that both plots can be put in the same figure. The code can be adjusted to the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('Pokemon.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')

# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.relplot(x='Attack', y='Defense', hue='Stage', data=df)
sns.kdeplot(df.Attack, df.Defense)
plt.title('Density vs Scatter');
```

If you are using Jupyter as your IDE, make sure to put all the code under `# plot` in the same cell. For other IDEs, select and run the code together. Otherwise, they will show as two separate plots.

[image]

Comment: ohhhhh. Ok that makes sense. I figured it was due to the plots not lining up correctly in some way. Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting an error " TypeError: regplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hue' "

Comment: When I change it to color 'instead' of 'hue', I get " ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 'Stage' "

Comment: In seaborn's api, `hue` doesn't mean changing colors but "grouping variable that will produce elements with different colors". Thus, you should pass a categorical variable to it. If you wanna change the colors of the plot, you should set `palette` instead. I suggest you to take a moment to read [doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot).

Comment: Oh I see. I had an issue with my seaborn library not updating correctly in the jupyter notebook. Once I reinstalled and restarted it allowed me to use the relplot(). I had been using regplot() due to the confusion. Thank you for going more in depth with me.